# csv file adding and removing characters from rows

Tags: perl, sed, awk, text-processing, csv

I have a big csv full that looks like so

```
else if(a,b,c,d,e)
else if(a,b,c,d,f)
```

I want to make it look like so

```
else if(a+x==b and b+x==c and c+x==d and d+x==e)
else if(a+x==b and b+x==c and c+x==d and d+x==f)
```

I don't always have 5 variables, some rows have less than that, 5 is maximum, 2 is minimum.

basically remove the commas and add after each variable, `var+x==var2 and var2+x==var3`; making it look like a C++ if statement. Is that doable in sed, awk or perl? I'm mostly interested in awk, for learning purposes, but any solution is good if it works.

Comment: did you want a space before `(` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj not necessarily, i edited my question, i want to edit whats inside the `()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the `perl` part and try this:

```
awk -F',' '{x = $1"+x=="$2; \
    for (i=2; i< NF; i++) { \
         x = x " and " $i "+x=="$(i+1) \
    }; \
    print "else if" x \
}'
```

Effect:

```
$ echo '(a,b,c,d,e)' | awk -F',' '{x = $1"+x=="$2; \
quote>     for (i=2; i< NF; i++) { \
quote>          x = x " and " $i "+x=="$(i+1) \
quote>     }; \
quote>     print "else if" x \
quote> }'
else if(a+x==b and b+x==c and c+x==d and d+x==e)
```

It wouldn't be too difficult to make it work with the output of `perl` (with the `else if` already in), but using one tool for the job is better if it doesn't complicate things (as in this case).

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
echo "else if(a,b,c,d,e)" | perl -pe 's/,([a-z])(?=[^)])/+x==$1 and $1/g; s/,([a-z])/+x==$1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure textual python solution. It needs at least 2 variables, no maximum.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

sourcefile = "/path/to/sourcefile"

def newline(oldline):
    subject = oldline.replace(" ", "").split("(")[-1].replace(")", "").split(",")
    out = [subject[i]+"+x=="+subject[i+1] for i in range(len(subject)-1)]
    print("else if("+" and ".join(out)+")")

with open(sourcefile) as sc:
    for line in [line.strip() for line in sc.readlines()]:
        newline(line)
```

Copy it into an empty file, save it as `edit.py`, set the path to the sourcefile, run it by:

```
python3 /path/to/edit.py
```

it converts:

```
else if(a,b)
else if(a,b,c,d,f)
else if(a,b,c,d,f,q,t)
```

into:

```
else if(a+x==b)
else if(a+x==b and b+x==c and c+x==d and d+x==f)
else if(a+x==b and b+x==c and c+x==d and d+x==f and f+x==q and q+x==t)
```